# Why is my text font lighter than my math font?

Tags: fonts, math-mode, mathdesign

When I used packages like Mathdesign and give commands like `\setrmdefault{cmr}` or something like this, what used to happen is the Text Font used to get lighter whereas the Math font used to be darker. Why does this happen, and how can I prevent this from happening?

Comment: I think we need some more context here. Why would you load mathdesign, only to switch the default font back to Computer Modern? What's the point in that? What exactly are you trying to accomplish?

Also, please remove the fontspec tag from this question. What does it have to do with the fontspec package?

Comment: Also, a title that gives some indication of the specific problem is needed.

Comment: Actually I think you are all being unfair to Chandru1. I have the exact same issue with displaying PDF and using mathdesign + some other font. mathdesign blends the math and text fonts too well; I rather have more contrast that is why I choose a different font (eg, verdana or lucida). PDF generates gray text but black math. BTW most of the comments are just gang banging the OP for no reason but to score points. Are we in high school again?

Comment: And the issue appears to be the result of LaTeX (in my case, MiKTeX) not being able to find the font specified for the text. It will use a substitute font and will gray the text presummably to let you know. The solution is to check that you use the correct font name.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Chandru,

(First things first: we're all here to help.  However, you can make things easier on everyone by paying attention to the way you present your questions. Please don't be put off, life is one big learning game! But also please think of the community before throwing improperly considered questions to the group - we've all got better things to do than to help those who are too lazy to first try hard themselves.)

Now to your question... frabjous essentially answered it when he asked why you had loaded `mathdesign` (presumably with one of the `utopia`, `garamond` or `charter` options), only afterwards to change your document's default Roman font to `Computer Modern`.  Don't get me wrong, there is nothing wrong with this *per se*. I sometimes do things like this when wanting to pair another Roman typeface with the `mathdesign` math font set. Still, because they pair so poorly, it seems very *odd* to want to mix `CM` with `mathdesign`.  `Computer Modern` is an exceptionally light font; as you point out, too light for `mathdesign`.

Now, why not use `garamond` or `charter` as your primary Roman font?  The `mathdesign` package has been specifically tuned for them.  If for some strange reason you can't and you really need to stick with `cmr`, then why not dispense with `mathdesign` and `\usepackage{amsfonts}` with `\usepackage{amssymb}`?

If that doesn't suit your requirements, and you really like the 'lightness' of `Computer Modern`, you might consider replacing the line where you write `\usepackage[...]{mathdesign}` with (1) `\usepackage{lmodern}` or (2) with `\usepackage[light]{kpfonts}`, that is, with (1) Latin Modern or (2) Kepler Project fonts using the `light` option. Both are downloadable from [CTAN](http://www.ctan.org/).

Now, if none of that makes sense, or if it doesn't provide the answer you wanted or expected, here's what you should do:

- as others have mentioned, post another question that more precisely describes your problem and the nature of what you want sorted out, *including a better title*;
- read up on LaTeX font selection commands
- *stop trying to pair `Computer Modern` with `mathdesign` math fonts!*

Anyway, Chandru, please don't be deterred. TeX/LaTeX is a powerful but confusing beast, the fun is learning how to climb that wall to tame it to your needs. We're here to help you, but show us that you've done your best to solve your own problems before hitting on us.  In no time at all, you'll even be helping others! So, welcome to this board.

Comment: Nicely detailed answer (which I'll vote for when I've got some votes available: tomorrow!)

Comment: +1 That’s easily one of the most diplomatic posts I’ve seen on the internet.

Comment: +1 Congratulations, @Geoffrey, a really good, kindly answer which addresses not only the underlying question but also the questioner's inexperience.

Comment: +1 Great to see such consideration in our community!

Comment: I'm tempted to downvote the question some more to help Geoffrey get the Reversal badge ...